# How do I search ??_doc.xml file in a specified folder in Finder?

Tags: finder, search

I have a lot of `??_doc.xml` files in a folder, it's like:

```
13_doc.xml
16_doc.xml
87_doc.xml
```

The filenames are all like two digits with `_doc.xml` combined together.

I want to search them and have them showed in folder, and when I type ??_doc.xml in the search box, I get nothing.

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my query? What should I type there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Finder search box does not support wildcards. You can add additional criteria to narrow down your search, though.

1. Enter **_doc** in the search field to start a search.
2. In the bar that appears (showing "Search: This Mac" etc) click the plus sign button all the way to the right.
3. In the new row that appears, in the first combobox, select *Name*, then in the next one select *Contains*, then in the empty text box type **_doc** (without wildcards or the file extension).
4. Click the plus sign button all the way to the right of this new row.
5. In the first combobox of the second row, choose *Kind*. In the second combobox, choose *Other*. In the empty text box type **xml** (without the leading period).

This will narrow down your search to files whose names contain **_doc** and whose extensions are **xml**.

Comment: Thanks very much. I finally know how my search in Finder works after switching from Windows to OS X for years!

Comment: You're welcome. There are lots of options to play with there, and you can save a search to use it again quickly in the future.